# Django 404 error

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have created two URL's, both of which go to the same view. One produces a 404 error and the other one does not.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from playerteamstats import views

urlpatterns = [
    # e.g. /stats
    url(r'^$', views.stats_index, name='index'), #Renders page
    # e.g. /stats/player
    url(r'^player/$', views.stats_index, name='player'), #Throws 404 error
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from playerteamstats.models import Player,Team

def stats_index(request):
    return render_to_response('stats_index.html')
```

**urls.py (root)**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^fixtures/$', include('fixtures.urls')),
    url(r'^stats/$', include('playerteamstats.urls')),
    #User public profile
    url(r'^(?P<username_in_url>\w+)/$', 'fantasymatchday_1.views.public_profile'),
)
```

**404 error**
[image: 404 Error]

It seems to match `/stats` to the app fine, but when I type in `/stats/player` it says it can't find the public username, as if it is looking for it on the root URL. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
url(r'^player/$', views.stats_index, name='player'), #Renders page
# e.g. /stats/player
url(r'^$', views.stats_index, name='index''), #Throws 404 error
```

The second url is the catch all. Django processes the urls sequentially. Your code above is only hitting the first url.

Comment: Nope,still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation :

> **Syntax of the urlpatterns variable:-**
>
> urlpatterns should be a Python list, in the format returned by the function django.conf.urls.patterns(). Always use patterns() to create the urlpatterns variable.

So try doing this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                url(r'^$', views.stats_index, name='index'),
                url(r'^player/$', views.stats_index, name='player'), 
               )
```

This should solve the problem.

See :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/